# Matching codes in two different files

Tags: python, sql

Whats the best method for matching occasionally occurring identifier codes, in two different large data files with millions of rows. I am thinking of creating in inner join via SQL.

Comment: SQL is used for databases, not data files.

Comment: There's a tool for that: https://github.com/harelba/q

Answer (score 0):

Since you're speaking about files with millions of rows, using a database to store the data is a good idea. You can than simply use inner join as you said.